# Clicking a link with data-method="POST" in Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

It seems it's not possible to send a POST-request with Capybara, even if that should be the direct result of a user action. For example, having a link with `data-method="POST"`, and subsequently clicking that link raises a server error for me:

```
No route matches [GET] "blabla"
```

Which makes sense, given that it should be a PUT-request (as specified in its attributes). Found some related posts about Capybara's inability to *directly* send POST-requests, but none about links with the `data-method` attribute set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "data-method" relies on using [the Rails Unobtrusive Javascript Driver](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method) to create a discrete form and post it to the server. If Rails UJS is not running properly or the client does not support JS a normal GET request will be sent instead - it is after all just a link and browsers send GET requests when you click links.

Capybara by default uses the RackTest driver which does not run javascript. Its not actually a real browser - its more like a browser simulator running on top of an XML parser.

You need to either use `button_to` instead which creates an actual form element and which does not rely on JS at all or [change the Capybara driver](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#selecting-the-driver) to a driver that runs javascript such as [Selenium Webdriver](https://www.selenium.dev/projects/) or [Apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition).

Comment: I forgot to specify, I actually already use Selenium webdriver - Javascript seems to work in all other tests, it's just unwilling to send non-GET requests via links. I'll try the `button_to` helper, though.

Comment: Using `button_to` solved it. No clue why we didn't use that before. *shrug* Thanks a ton, I had tried to refactor the link into a form and button myself, which didn't seem to work somehow, didn't know about this helper method.

Comment: @Knaapje using a bunch of forms instead of links result in a slightly heavier DOM but its well worth the tradeoff for "hardening" anything mission critical like a logout button.

Comment: Fully agree, I would have gone for the button initially if I had done the initial work on this functionality. My confusion mostly stemmed from the fact that Capybara completely ignored the `data-method` attribute (despite it being less idiomatic than using a button).